# webpack is using parent's node_modules and when there is node_modules in current directory

Tags: webpack

- parent-project

  - node_modules
  - child-project

    - node_modules

inside `child-project` I run `./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config conf/webpack.sns.config.js --watch`

webpack fails with an error message which says `parent-project/node_modules/less-loader/index.js` has undefined error.

I expect webpack to use `child-project/node_modules/less-loader`. why is it using the parent's one?